# Get the second bracket content using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to modify the content of the second square bracket for the following DOM

```
extra_fields_setting_name[1][0][extra_fields_setting_name_label]
```

i'm using the following for changing the content of the first bracket of the dom, like the following

```
replace ( /\[[^\]]+\]/, "[" + (new_number_here) + "]" );
```

but i can't get the second bracket content like the first, how can i do that ?

Comment: So in your example it should return `0`?

Comment: no in this example it only return 1 not 0, what i want to get is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this your exact input, you may try the below regex (*which uses [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*) to match only the contents of second square brackets.

```
[^\[\]]+(?=\]\[[^\]]+\]$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rC7kB0/2)

Example:

```
> var s = "extra_fields_setting_name[1][0][extra_fields_setting_name_label]"
undefined
> s.replace(/[^\[\]]+(?=\]\[[^\]]+\]$)/, "x")
'extra_fields_setting_name[1][x][extra_fields_setting_name_label]'
```

Comment: Thx, that's exactly what i wanted

Comment: But how is this giving match from a dynamic numbered bracket?

Comment: yep, it works only for the op's example. I already said that.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Yes I know, it was actually directed at OP as he wrote: `@anubhava but the number could be dynamic, the first number` below

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
(\[[^\]]+\])\[([^\]]+)\]
```

Matched group # 2 will give you content of 2nd brackets.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rC7kB0/1)

Comment: Sorry but that will only get the two brackets ( the first one and the second ), i need only to get the second bracket

Comment: @osos: I'm pretty sure that's not possible. You just need to replace with `$1[new number here]` though, that's not really a problem, is it?

Comment: Hmm without look behind and other PCRE features that will be little challenging. I will come back to my computer in an hour and try free things and update you.

Comment: @anubhava but the number could be dynamic, the first number

Comment: Hmm it might be possible with an ugly looking regex, but I don't want to submit that unrated regex since I am on mobile at present.